# cmd.exe ignoring /t color when using /c instead of /k

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, windows-11

Let's say I have a simple `.bat` file called `foo.bat` containing just

```
@echo off
:dostuff
echo bar
timeout /t 2 /nobreak
goto :dostuff
```

If I run it from prompt `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.3155]` with `start cmd.exe /t:04 /k foo.bat` then a terminal will open with a black background and red text

If I run it with `start cmd.exe /t:04 /c foo.bat` a normal black background and white text prompt opens.

I haven't seen any mention in Microsoft's documentation that `/t` is not supported by `/c`, is there a way to have the same color behavior as with `/k`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I haven't seen any mention in Microsoft's documentation that `/t` is not supported by `/c`

After looking at the [source code](https://github.com/tongzx/nt5src/blob/daad8a087a4e75422ec96b7911f1df4669989611/Source/XPSP1/NT/base/cmd/cinit.c#L324-L339), it seems that this combination is deliberately not supported, even if that's not documented.

Use the COLOR command built-in to Cmd – either put `color 04` directly in your script, or if you don't want to do that, then provide `color 04 && foo.bat` as the command for the shortcut:

```
cmd /k color 04 && foo.bat

start cmd /k color 04 ^&^& foo.bat
```

(Something like that. The escaping of `&&` depends on context.)

Comment: mmm, I wonder why they decided to not support it (or why it's not mentioned in the docs). Anyway, with a little bit of tinkering to insert `color` in the real script this worked like a charm